# Did this thumbscrew fall off my Kia Sedona?

Tags: kia, screw, sedona

I found this fairly large coarse thread thumbscrew in my driveway, near the front of where my van is parked.  I have a new 2018 Kia Sedona.  Any idea if this fell off my minivan?  And if so, where I might find where it goes?

I've checked under the hood, around the panels, under the van, and did not see any obvious place where it may have come from.

[image: Thumbscrew 1]

[image: Thumbscrew 2]

Comment: IMO that looks like a thumbscrew from a camera tripod or similar.

Comment: From my limited experience, thumbscrews are fairly uncommon in automobiles. Things usually need to be secured considerably tighter, or just use plastic clips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that is a thumbscrew or locking screw for a camera tripod or similar.

I don’t consider it is a bung or stopper screw for a reservoir on a car. Some tanks may have a drain cock but that is likely to have an external or internal hexagon head.